# Where Dinâmico no Linq to Entities

Tags: c#

Caros,

Preciso realizar um where dinâmico, em um Linq to Entities. Pesquisei algumas soluções mas nenhuma conseguiu realizar o que preciso. Até então, tenho o seguinte switch:

```
    public TransportadorasGrid ObterTransportadorasBusca(Int32 PageNumber, Int32 PageSize, String NomeTransportadora, Boolean Status, Guid cdUsuario, String Idioma)
    {
        TransportadorasGrid Grid = new TransportadorasGrid();
        List<Transportadora> Transp = new List<Transportadora>();
        Int32 idLoja = Identidade.ObterIdLoja(cdUsuario);

        try
        {
            using (IFEcommerce ctx = new IFEcommerce())
            {
                BaseEcommerce.Definir(ctx);
                ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                Int32 StartLine = PageNumber * PageSize;

                Expression<Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, object>> ExpressionOrdenacao;
                String NomeColunaBusca = String.Empty;

                switch (Idioma)
                {
                    case "en-US":
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_EN;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_EN";
                        break;
                    case "es-ES":
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_ES;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_ES";
                        break;
                    case "fr-FR":
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_FR;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_FR";
                        break;
                    case "de-DE":
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_DE;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_DE";
                        break;
                    case "it-IT":
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_IT;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_IT";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_PT;
                        NomeColunaBusca = "Label_Nome_PT";
                        break;
                }


                //Eu coloquei o NomeProp no where Somente para exemplificar...
                List<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras> tr = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras
                    .Where(u => u.idLoja == idLoja && u.flExcluido == false && NomeProp == NomeTransportadora)
                    .OrderBy(ExpressionOrdenacao)
                    .Skip(StartLine)
                    .Take(PageSize)
                    .ToList();

                List<tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto> AcoesAcDesc = ctx
                    .tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto
                    .ToList();

                List<ParametroAcrescimoDesconto> Acoes = ObterParametrosAcrescimoDesconto(cdUsuario);

                foreach (vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras trnsp in tr)
                {
                    Transportadora t = new Transportadora();

                    tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto Frete = AcoesAcDesc.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idTipoDescontoAcrescimo == trnsp.idTipoDescontoAcrescimoFrete);
                    tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto Pedido = AcoesAcDesc.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idTipoDescontoAcrescimo == trnsp.idTipoDescontoAcrescimoPedido);

                    t.AcaoFrete = Acoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CodigoParametro == Frete.cdTipoDescontoAcrescimo);
                    t.AcaoPedido = Acoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CodigoParametro == Pedido.cdTipoDescontoAcrescimo); 
                    t.CodigoTransportadora = trnsp.cdTransportadora;
                    t.LabelInformacoes = trnsp.lbInformacoes;
                    t.LabelNomeExibicao = trnsp.lbNomeExibicao;
                    t.Traducoes = new List<TraducoesLabel>();
                    t.ValorFrete = trnsp.vlDescontoAcrescimoFrete;
                    t.ValorPedido = trnsp.vlDescontoAcrescimoPedido;
                    t.Status = trnsp.flStatus;

                    Transp.Add(t);
                }

                Grid.Transportadoras = Transp;

                Int32 Count = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras.Count(u => u.idLoja == idLoja && u.flExcluido == false);

                Grid.Count = Count;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(Exc).Throw();
        }

        return Grid;
    }
```

Até aí Ok. Porém preciso utilizar para filtro a coluna selecionada pelo switch. (Eu coloquei o NomeProp no where somente para exemplificar)

```
List<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras> tr = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras
    .Where(u => u.idLoja == idLoja && u.flExcluido == false && NomeProp == NomeTransportadora)
    .OrderBy(ExpressionOrdenacao)
    .Skip(StartLine)
    .Take(PageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Eu tentei utilizar o código abaixo, mas aparentemente funciona apenas com LINQ to objects.

```
List<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras> tr = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras
    .Where(u => u.idLoja == idLoja && u.flExcluido == false && u.GetType().GetProperty(NomeProp).GetValue(u, null) == NomeTransportadora)
    .OrderBy(ExpressionOrdenacao)
    .Skip(StartLine)
    .Take(PageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Alguma luz ?

Comment: Idioma vem da onde?

Comment: Idioma é uma String que vem na assinatura do Método.

Comment: Exemplo: `ExpressionOrdenacao("it-IT")` ?

Comment: Não... ExpressionOrdenacao eu utilizo para OrderBy... (definido na linha 1, antes do switch: Expression<Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, object>> ExpressionOrdenacao;)..ele é apenas um System.Linq.Expression

Comment: Bom vamos ver se eu entendi agora, o Where tem que depender do Swith para funcionar?

Comment: Sim.. de acordo com o idioma escolhido no switch, devo utilizar uma determinada propriedade no Where (ou Label_Nome_EN, ou Label_Nome_ES ou Label_Nome_PT, etc).

Comment: Outra duvida quem passa esse valor por exemplo `it-IT` porque ai eu criaria  um método de extensão fazendo as duas soluções!

Comment: Vem na assinatura do método... public TransportadorasGrid ObterTransportadorasBusca(Int32 PageNumber, Int32 PageSize, String NomeTransportadora, Boolean Status, Guid cdUsuario, String Idioma).. é apenas uma string que contém um dos valores dentro do switch

Comment: Então por favor coloque tudo isso na sua pergunta, não tem como saber se você não postar tudo que precisamos saber para responder uma determinada duvida! Ok? se poderia?

Comment: Claro.. Editei a questão @Virgulio Novic.

Comment: Faz um teste ve se dá algum erro e me fala!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize também uma ***expressão*** para definir o filtro dessa pesquisa e que tenha relação com a ordenação, ***exemplo***:

```
public TransportadorasGrid ObterTransportadorasBusca(Int32 PageNumber, Int32 PageSize, String NomeTransportadora, Boolean Status, Guid cdUsuario, String Idioma)
{
    TransportadorasGrid Grid = new TransportadorasGrid();
    List<Transportadora> Transp = new List<Transportadora>();
    Int32 idLoja = Identidade.ObterIdLoja(cdUsuario);

    try
    {
        using (IFEcommerce ctx = new IFEcommerce())
        {
            BaseEcommerce.Definir(ctx);
            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            Int32 StartLine = PageNumber * PageSize;

            Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, object> ExpressionOrdenacao;
            Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, bool> ExpressionWhere;
            String NomeColunaBusca = String.Empty;

            switch (Idioma)
            {
                case "en-US":
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_EN;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_EN == NomeTransportadora                 
                    break;
                case "es-ES":
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_ES;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_ES == NomeTransportadora                 
                    break;
                case "fr-FR":
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_FR;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_FR == NomeTransportadora                     
                    break;
                case "de-DE":
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_DE;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_DE == NomeTransportadora                     
                    break;
                case "it-IT":
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_IT;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_IT == NomeTransportadora                     
                    break;
                default:
                    ExpressionOrdenacao = p => p.Label_Nome_PT;
                    ExpressionWhere = c => c.idLoja == idLoja && c.flExcluido == false && c.Label_Nome_PT == NomeTransportadora                     
                    break;
            }


            //Eu coloquei o NomeProp no where Somente para exemplificar...
            List<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras> tr = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras
                .Where(ExpressionWhere)
                .OrderBy(ExpressionOrdenacao)
                .Skip(StartLine)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .ToList();

            List<tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto> AcoesAcDesc = ctx
                .tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto
                .ToList();

            List<ParametroAcrescimoDesconto> Acoes = ObterParametrosAcrescimoDesconto(cdUsuario);

            foreach (vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras trnsp in tr)
            {
                Transportadora t = new Transportadora();

                tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto Frete = AcoesAcDesc.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idTipoDescontoAcrescimo == trnsp.idTipoDescontoAcrescimoFrete);
                tb_Param_TipoAcrescimoDesconto Pedido = AcoesAcDesc.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idTipoDescontoAcrescimo == trnsp.idTipoDescontoAcrescimoPedido);

                t.AcaoFrete = Acoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CodigoParametro == Frete.cdTipoDescontoAcrescimo);
                t.AcaoPedido = Acoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CodigoParametro == Pedido.cdTipoDescontoAcrescimo); 
                t.CodigoTransportadora = trnsp.cdTransportadora;
                t.LabelInformacoes = trnsp.lbInformacoes;
                t.LabelNomeExibicao = trnsp.lbNomeExibicao;
                t.Traducoes = new List<TraducoesLabel>();
                t.ValorFrete = trnsp.vlDescontoAcrescimoFrete;
                t.ValorPedido = trnsp.vlDescontoAcrescimoPedido;
                t.Status = trnsp.flStatus;

                Transp.Add(t);
            }

            Grid.Transportadoras = Transp;

            Int32 Count = ctx.vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras.Count(u => u.idLoja == idLoja && u.flExcluido == false);

            Grid.Count = Count;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Exc)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(Exc).Throw();
    }

    return Grid;
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Expressões lambda (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)
- [Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions)
- [Expression Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Quase isso nobre @Virgilio Novic, mas sua resposta me deu o norte que precisava. Ao invés de Expression<Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, object>> ExpressionWhere; eu precisei utilizar o Func<vw_Painel_FretesLoja_GridTransportadoras, bool> ExpressionWhere... Com isso funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda e vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Voce tem toda razão... @JulioSoares é bool com Where.